# Adding a gradient layer to a table view cell element dependant on the cell index path

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, gradient

I am having difficulty adding a gradient layer as the background to an element inside a table view cell. The gradient layer is dependant on the cell index path. I have an `enum` of Colors which uses the `indexPath` as its `rawValue`. The desired output is something simple like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fdu7.jpg)

This is the function which creates the gradient layer. I used this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/3gUNg3Jhjwo) to write the function.

```
func setGradientBackground(colorOne: UIColor, colorTwo: UIColor, name: String) {
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = bounds
    gradient.colors = [colorOne.cgColor, colorTwo.cgColor]
    gradient.locations = [0, 1]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    gradient.name = name
    layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
}
```

To add the gradient to the element in the table view cell have tried a couple of things. Currently I am looping through visible cells to add the layer. i have tried calling from `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. It is the only time I have seen the gradients applied.

There are two problems I've seen. The app becomes unusable because I think this function is called more or less continuously when something on the view changes. And also the layers are drawn over everything else in the cells.

```
func configTableCells() {
    guard let cells = self.tableView.visibleCells as? [GroupTableCell] else {return}
    for (i, cell) in cells.enumerated() {
        if shouldAddSubLayer(cell) {
            guard let colorOne = Colors(rawValue: i)?.classicColor,
                let colorTwo = Colors(rawValue: i)?.alternativeColor else {continue}
            cell.taskInfoCollectionView.setGradientBackground(colorOne: colorOne,
                                                              colorTwo: colorTwo,
                                                              name: cellLayerName)
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to add the layer in `cellForRowAt` and also `willDisplay Cell` but this didn't work. I believe this is because the cell does not 'exist' yet so adding a layer makes no difference.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: groupCellId, for: indexPath) as! GroupTableCell
    cell.groupNameLabel.text = "Group Name"
    cell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(self, forRow: indexPath.row)
    if shouldAddSubLayer(cell) {
        if let colorOne = Colors(rawValue: indexPath.row)?.classicColor,
            let colorTwo = Colors(rawValue: indexPath.row)?.alternativeColor {
        cell.taskInfoCollectionView.setGradientBackground(colorOne: colorOne,
                                                          colorTwo: colorTwo,
                                                          name: cellLayerName)
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Also I have included this function because I read on another stackOverflow question i should check if the cell already has the layer to avoid continuously adding it. (I can't link the question as i can't find it now)

```
func shouldAddSubLayer(_ cell: GroupTableCell) -> Bool {
    guard let sublayers = cell.layer.sublayers else {return true}
    return sublayers.filter({ $0.name == cellLayerName }).count == 0
}
```

Any suggestions on how to get this working welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [VisualEffect](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uivisualeffectview)

add the below code in your `ViewDidLoad()`

```
if (!UIAccessibilityIsReduceTransparencyEnabled()) {
tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
tableView.backgroundView = blurEffectView

//if inside a popover
if let popover = navigationController?.popoverPresentationController {
    popover.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}

//if you want translucent vibrant table view separator lines
tableView.separatorEffect = UIVibrancyEffect(blurEffect: blurEffect)}
```

Comment: thanks ben, bit of modification required but seemed to get it working, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might find this useful, the changes required to get it working..

Using Visual Effect that Ben suggested I was able to get this working. I've never used Visual Effects so not sure exactly why it works. Again there are probably some improvements I need

In the custom table cell class i added a `UIVisualEffectView`. In its content view i added the element whose background i wanted to change.

> *Add any subviews to the contentView property of the visual effect view.
>    Do not add subviews directly to the visual effect view itself*

```
lazy var visualEffectView: UIVisualEffectView = {
    let v = UIVisualEffectView()
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.contentView.addSubview(taskInfoCollectionView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        taskInfoCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.topAnchor),
        taskInfoCollectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.leadingAnchor),
        taskInfoCollectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.trailingAnchor),
        taskInfoCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.bottomAnchor),
    ])
    return v
}()
```

Back in the controller i use this function to add the gradient to the visual effect view which takes the index and the cell

```
func addGradient(_ i: Int, _ cell: GroupTableCell) {
    guard let colorOne = Colors(rawValue: i)?.classicColor,
        let colorTwo = Colors(rawValue: i)?.alternativeColor else {return}
    cell.visualEffectView.contentView.setGradientBackground(colorOne: colorOne,
                                                      colorTwo: colorTwo,
                                                      name: cellLayerName)
}
```

I still had to add a function to `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. This is to configure the cells that `cellForRowAt` does not. The property `setGradients` is initially set to true but then immediately set to false, so it's not continuously called like before.

```
var setGradients = true    

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    if setGradients {
        configTableCells()
        setGradients = false
    }
}

func configTableCells() {
    guard let cells = self.tableView.visibleCells as? [GroupTableCell] else {return}
    for (i, cell) in cells.enumerated() {
        if shouldAddSubLayer(cell) {
            addGradient(i, cell)
        }
    }
}
```

Then finally in `cellForRowAt` this appears to take care of the rest and everything seems to run smoothly with no lag.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: GROUP_CELL_ID, for: indexPath) as! GroupTableCell
    cell.groupNameLabel.text = "Group Name"
    cell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(self, forRow: indexPath.row)
    addGradient(indexPath.row, cell)
    return cell
}
```

I tried this with using a `UIView`, not a `UIVisualEffectView`. but the gradients overlay the cell content again. so a `UIVisualEffectView` is required